# Passing Web3 & Contracts Between Components - React Redux & MetaMask

Tags: web3js, metamask, web3j

Curious what's the best way to access and pass a `web3 contract instance` provided by MetaMask between components when using react-redux.

At this point, I'm tempted to do the following for both `web3` and the contract:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    setWeb3: (web3) => {
        dispatch({
            type: 'WEB3',
            value: web3
        })
    },    
    setContract: (contractInstance) => {
        dispatch({
            type: 'CONTRACT',
            value: contractInstance
        })
    },  
});
```

With the following initialization in `ComponentDidMount`

```
 setInterval(() => {
                web3js.eth.getAccounts((error, accounts) => {
                    if (accounts.length > 0) {
                        this.props.setWeb3(web3js);

                        //Do contract initialization...
                        this.props.setContract(contractInstance);
                 }
                });
            }, 2500);
```

I know that it's not best practice to be putting non-JSON, non-serializable data into the props.

Suggestions for a best practice? I suppose an alternative would be to create a separate .js file with getter/setters for the instances. Am I overthinking this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure what you ended up doing here, but when I ran into a similar issue, I decided to put `web3` into my selectors.  That was important because the Provider URL could change over time, so I wanted to make sure that Web3 always had the most up-to-date value from the Redux store.  The big perk of doing this as a selector is that you don't need to worry about any imperative update logic -- the selector just always returns an up-to-date web3.